# PHP live support chat software

Tags: chat, php

I'm looking for a php script that allows my users on my site to chat with a support agent. I'm looking for something like [this](http://www.kayako.com/) but without being so [expensive](http://www.kayako.com/pricing).

Context: I am running a Minecraft hosting company and I would like live support to aid my users in either sales or support.

Specific features I am looking for:

- Must be stand-alone (as in I don't want my users connecting to another website to get support)
- Shouldn't have to pay per agent
- Costs less than $50
- Must have ajax support
- Must have a "chat box" for users to start a chat with an agent
- Ability to insert the chat box code into any webpage
- Ability to select different departments
- Admin area for agents to go to, and chat with users
- Notification for when a new chat is waiting to be handled
- In the event that there is no agents online, the user can "leave a message" for when an agent does come online
- Ability to transfer a chat session to another agent or department
- Ability for the user to download a chat log of their session

Optional

- Ability for agents to see what users are connected to what webpage
- Ability for agents to ask a user to go into a chat with them
- Bonus if there is a desktop client for agents

I will take recommendations for a monthly price as well (so long as it is not per-agent) but it is preferred for a one-time price.

Comment: Your requirements are too specific, you should make them general so that you can get some relevant answers

Comment: @Mr.Alien I'm neither the OP nor am I affiliated with him, but these requirements are pretty generic IMO

Comment: Agreed @TheDude I would want all of these features too

Comment: http://livehelperchat.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found one that matches all but one requirement*

**[PHP - Live Chat](http://codecanyon.net/item/php-live-chat/6261119)** (One time purchase: $22, Lifetime Updates)

Features:

- Standalone
- Less than $50
- Ajax Support
- Has chat box for users to start chat
- Can add chat box to any page
- Can select different departments
- Has admin panel
- Leave a message support
- Ability to transfer session to different departments
- Ability to see what users are connected to what webpages
- Easy setup
- Custom colors
- Chat history
- Canned messages
- Unlimited departments
- Unlimited operators (agents)
- Sound alerts
- Typing indicator
- Responsive design
- Translation ready

*Currently your requirement of "Ability for the user to download a chat log of their session" is not available but it is going to be added in the next update according to Gnt Studio

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since the item is no longer available, if you need an alternative and also opensource, you can try [ppmessage](https://github.com/PPMESSAGE/ppmessage).

> With PPMessage, you can chat with visitor or customer via Web or mobile App as open source Intercom alternative.

PPmessage has [SDK](https://ppmessage.gitbooks.io/ppbook-en/content/part2/ppcom/index.html), for web, android and ios. Here is some ocassions :

> Classic occasions: suppose you have a website with its own user system and you integrate PPCom with you website. Your website user can perform operations like sign in, change profile and log out. When user performs these operations, you should invoke Web SDK API to display PPCom correctly.

It has events :

1. User open your website
2. User sign in
3. User modify his profile
4. User sign out from your website

To install it, it's easy :

```
git clone https://github.com/PPMESSAGE/ppmessage.git
cd ppmessage
# mac
bash ppmessage/scripts/set-up-ppmessage-on-mac.sh
# linux
bash ppmessage/scripts/set-up-ppmessage-on-linux.sh
# watch the logs
./ppmessage.py
```

Then go to 127.0.0.1:8945, and follow the instruction. And here is interesting part, it has test function, to make sure everything is work, go to 127.0.0.1:8945/ppconsole/#/app/settings/integrate. You will see in the right bottom an icon to chat, that's for customer. And go to 127.0.0.1:8945/ppkefu/#/app/conversation-list as web administrator to reply the chat.